# Excel VBA ActiveCell formula convert to value

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a formula in a cell that calculates a given date.  I want to write a VBA macro that will take the formula, convert it to the resulting date value and copy that value to another/adjacent cell.

I've attempted to record the macro using "F2" and "F9" however the VBA script returns, e.g.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "12/31/2009".
```

I want to write the macro to work in future years where the formula for the date cell could be 12/31/2012, 2013, etc.  I have built formulas to eliminate effect of leap year, so I can't just add 365 to derive next year.

Answer (score 2):

This will copy the value and format from the current active cell to the cell to the right

```
Sub CopyValue()
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = ActiveCell.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = ActiveCell.NumberFormat
End Sub
```